# How to reset cell content to `System.DBNull`

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` which has a `DataTable` as its `ItemsSource`. The grid is meant to be used for only `double` values. However, for some cells no data is specified so the value can be `null`. (Actually the type is `DBNull`). This all works fine until I start editing a cell and then decide I don't want any values in that cell and then try to leave it empty and continue. The `DataGrid` does not let me do this. How can I get it to work in a way so I'll be able to reset the initial `null` value to a cell if I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a Value Converter...so you can set the value to DBNull if the cell is empty.
But I think you have to define columns manually...

in xaml:

```
<Window xmlns:conv="PathToConverter">
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:ValueConverter x:Key="valueConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=""
                            Binding="{Binding doubleValue
                                    , Converter={StaticResource valueConverter}
                                    , Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
...
</Window>
```

your converter class has to implement the `IValueConverter` interface

Answer (score 0):

Are you having a problem with validation?

Otherwise, just "Esc"-ing will cancel the current edit, I believe.

Comment: I am having a problem with validation.